# System.BadImageFormatException when running XUnit 2.2.0 unit test in VS 2017 against a full .net framework asp.net core project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, unit-testing

**Info about my setup:**

- Resharper 2016.3.2
- XUnit 2.2.0
- VS 2017 RTM
- Test Project .net 4.5.2
- Asp.net Core Project .net 4.5.2

**Repo Steps:**

1. Create an asp.net core site targeting .net 4.5.2
2. Add a unit test project or class library to the solution and reference the asp.net project
3. Create a xunit Fact test that targets a class in the asp.net project
4. Run the unit test using resharper test runner

**Error:**

System.BadImageFormatException
Could not load file or assembly 'AFAEMS, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
   at AFAEMS.Tests.Class1.return_errors_if_missing_fields()

**Notes:**

I've done a lot of searching and cannot find any similar issues to this. I can run a unit test with a simple assert that is not targeting the asp.net core class files. I couldn't get the VS test runner to find my xunit tests (maybe b/c resharper test runner is enabled?).

These were things I found but don't indicate how to fix with the new xproj and app.config using MSBuild for VS 2017.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/05/30/announcing-mstest-framework-support-for-net-core-rc2-asp-net-core-rc2/

[Testing Asp.Net Core on full .NET framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39167176/testing-asp-net-core-on-full-net-framework)

https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/926

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio change the target from “X86 ” to “Any CPU”.

Also,you will get this error if you try to host an application with a 32-bit assembly reference ,on IIS running on a 64 bit server/machine. To fix this error set "Enable 32 bit applications" flag to true in Advanced settings of the application pool hosting the application in IIS.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this fixed by using the following settings in my Resharper unit testing options.

[image: resharper options unit testing]

Comment: Same here - but I'd also changed to x64 from Test -> Test Settings -> Default Processor Architecture.